# Does Microsoft Visual Studio have a layout editor?

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio

I am looking to see if anyone knows if Microsoft Visual Studios has any layout editor extensions/feature that is similar to Android Studios layout editor. I had more experience using Android Studio, however since I needed a program for both iOS and Android, I had to use Visual Studios for my company. It would make my life a hella a lot easier if I had this feature instead of me relying on HTML/CSS codes to adjust the buttons/text within a page. Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with some extensions or [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/designer-walkthrough?tabs=vswin)